# How to handle user enable location & return to app

Tags: windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml

My app need to access location service, for that I am asking user to whether to enable location, if user says yes, then I am opening location settings. Upto this is working. But how to detect/handle when user coming from location page to my application page.

Here is my code

```
private async Task<Geoposition> getCurrentLocation()
        {
            Geoposition position = null;
            Geolocator locator = new Geolocator() { DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 10 };
            var flag = true;
            try
            {
                position = await locator.GetGeopositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromHours(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
                flag = false;
            }
            catch (Exception uae)
            {

            }
            if (flag)
            {
                await ShowLocationPage();
            }
        }
```

getCurrentLocation method called when page is loaded. If it didnt get user location then ShowLocationPage method get called.

```
   private static async Task ShowLocationPage()
    {
        ContentDialog cd = new ContentDialog(){
            Content = "Application want to access your location. Would you like to turn on Location Services?",
            PrimaryButtonText = "Yes",
            SecondaryButtonText = "No"
        };
        var result = await cd.ShowAsync();            if (result == ContentDialogResult.Primary)
        {
          var x = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings-location:"));
        }

    }
```

My problem is how to detect that user return from location page, so I can check for geo-information again.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to get this going is to check if your app get's focus again ( or is resumed ).
With the new wp RT this has changed a bit against wp SL.
A bit to long to explain here in StackO answer, but a very compleet explanation is up here http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2013/07/24/return-xaml-store-app

Some disscussion about it was up on twitter few days back: https://twitter.com/rschu/status/498836593269305344